# get value of TD to show in modal Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I have a dynamic table.

[image]

In the table above, I'm trying to get the value of the column `Time Left`. Here's my JS code:

```
$('#checkout').on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
     var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
     var id = button.data('id')
     var room = button.data('room')
     var timeleft = $("#tss").text();

     $("#id_checkout").val(id);
     $("#room_checkout").val(room);
     $("#timeleft").val(timeleft);

      console.log(timeleft)
});
```

And here's my **blade.php**

```
    <tbody>
         @foreach ($customers as $c)
             <tr class="item">
                 <td hidden class="row_id" id="row_id">{{$c->id}}</td>
                 <td scope="row" class="font-weight-bold">{{$c->room}}</td>
                 <td>{{$c->room_type}}</td>
                 <td>{{$c->name}}</td>
                 <td>{{$c->check_in_hrs}}</td>
                 <td id="time">
                     {{ $ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F Y H:i:s', $c->time_out)->format('F d Y, h:i A') }}
                 </td>

                 <td id="tss" class="tss"> Please wait... // This is the column I'm trying to get.
                 </td>

                 <td>{{$c->assistant}}</td>
                 <td>
                     <a href="#" data-target="#extend" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{$c->id}}" data-room={{$c->room}}>
                         <i class="fa fa-plus-circle lblue fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" href="#"></i>
                     </a>
                     <a href="#" data-target="#checkout" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{$c->id}}" data-room={{$c->room}}>
                         <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt red fa-2x"></i>    
                     </a>                                        
                 </td>
             </tr>
         @endforeach
     </tbody>
```

When I run my JS function, I only get the value of the first row of the table.

Comment: Use classes on your table cells instead of IDs. IDs are supposed to be unique and this may be why you're only getting the first column's value back.

Comment: It is because you have multiple `<td>` tags with `id="tss` and your javascript is fetching you the first only.

Comment: @GusRuss89, tried to use class `tss` yet it still returns the same value

Comment: Is `id="checkout"` one of the arrows? Then that needs to be a class too and you can use closest("tr") to find the .tss

Comment: Okay, class `tss` did solve the problem. I just didnt use it properly. Thank you!